# How to ensure Chrome remembers open tabs?

Tags: google-chrome

For the past couple of weeks, Chrome has been forgetting which tabs I had open in the previous session, and opens with a blank tab.

I've been doing some testing, and it appears that Chrome is now treating the WhatsApp, Basecamp, Slack, etc. external Chrome **apps** as if they were Chrome **windows**. Since Chrome remembers only the tabs in the last window you close, I must remember to always open Chrome first and close it last. I forget half the time, and lose my pinned tabs, and whatever I was reading.

Any idea how to fix it?